# .Net Core App - command line Format Exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, command-line, .net-core

I'm following this guide :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?tabs=aspnetcore2x

When I'm trying to run the .exe file with the **--console** command line argument im getting the following error  message:-

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Value for switch '--console' is missing.

Here is the Main method on my Program class.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

            var pathToContentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            if (isService)
            {
                var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
                pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
            }

            var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            if (isService)
            {
                host.RunAsCustomService();
            }
            else
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
```

I've ensured I'm running the command line argument from folder path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core configuration system does not accept switches without values. It expects to be able to create key-value pairs from the parameters, so be sure to not forward this argument:

```
var webHostcArgs = args.Where(arg => arg != "--console").ToArray();
var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(webHostcArgs)
…
```

Comment: Also pass the filtered args array to ConfigurationBuilder.AddCommandLine